# How to rewrite this MySQL query with Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have such Eloquent Query:

```
$data->replies = Reply::where('thread_id', '=', $thread)
                ->with('user')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                ->paginate(20);
```

And i also want to count, how many replies user has written. I was able to write such MySQL code:

```
SELECT user_id, text, 
(SELECT count(*) from replies AS t2 WHERE t1.user_id=t2.user_id) AS cnt 
FROM replies AS t1 
WHERE thread_id = 910 ORDER BY `t1`.`user_id` ASC
```

But i have no idea, how to inject this query into my eloquent query.

Comment: Laravel/Eloquent supports `DB::raw()`, which you could paste your existing query into and receive results. That being said, what have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a code-conversion service; you need to show some effort, and if you have a specific issue with something, *then* post a question.

Comment: I have tried building sub selects, but with no success. $sub = Reply::select('count(*)')
    ->where('user_id', '=', '55');

DB::table(DB::raw("($sub->toSql()) as t1"))
    ->mergeBindings($sub)

Comment: Ok, but by saying "... but with no success", you're kinda missing the point of the words "if you have a *specific* issue". Are you getting an error? What is it? etc etc. Also, when adding code, please edit your question and try to use as little code in comments as necessary. Get's hard to read :P

Comment: Rewrite it to a JOIN query. But it doesn't look like this query makes much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to write additional query for it. You can use

```
$data->count();
```